# Combining \includepdf with {sidewaysfigure} environment

Tags: pdfpages, sidewaysfigure

Dear fellow TeXnocrats,

I wonder if it is possible to combine the `sidewaysfigure` package with `\includepdf` to the effect that every odd page of a multi-page pdf is turned 90° and every even page turned -90°. I would like to avoid to have to load each page separately.

The current code does not produce any PDFs to be included in the main document:

```
begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includepdf[pages=-,width=1.2\textwidth,pagecommand={}]{Back/msappendixprints/kaplain/kaplain}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
```

By itself, the `\includepdf` ... segment works fine, but not inside the `sidewaysfigure` environment.

Help would be appreciated. Kindly!

Comment: Please post a compile document or at least the document code that has this issue

Comment: why `sidewaysfigure` is necessary? you can get what you want without it.

Comment: No. sidewaysfigure is a one-page float. You can't use if for multipage content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. The idea is to define

```
\newcommand*\side{90}
```

and then use

```
\includepdf[pages=-,width=1.2\textwidth,pagecommand={\xdef\side{\the\numexpr-\side\relax}},angle=\side]{myfile}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand*\side{}

\newcommand*\includorientedpdf[1]{%
\ifodd\value{page}%           % or another check like \isodd
\renewcommand*\side{90}%      % or -90
\else
\renewcommand*\side{-90}%
\fi
\includepdf[pages=-,width=1.2\textwidth,pagecommand={\xdef\side{\the\numexpr-\side\relax}},angle=\side]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\includorientedpdf{myfile}
\end{document}
```